# Running Vim on Windows: is there a best way?

Tags: discussion

Can I even ask about how to "best" install Vim on windows? I generally a have a unix problem there... and it affects vim in that gVim mostly works, but then some odd things aren't working (like tab completing help topics nor commands nor files) and running vim in the `cmd.exe` messes up the colors very much (compared to in Mintty, but that's another issue where I have multiple vims around now just because some environments come with their own).

Actually you might look at this question and let me know if it can be adapted to be basically: here's all the ways I could run vim, is there a right way?
https://superuser.com/questions/1016899/windows-10s-story-for-unix

Oh and that's deleted now. Allow me to um... include the text here for reference:

> What's the story for Unix on Windows 10?
>
> I recently moved from MacOS X 10.11 to Windows 10, and am sorely
>   missing the one true unix installation for the operating system.
>
> I ask due to the following experiences:
>
> 1. I installed [git for windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and got a little compact bit of unix in `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` which runs
>
>    - [mintty](http://mintty.github.io/) using
>    - [mingw64](http://mingw.org/) running with `bin` `dev` `etc` `tmp` `usr` confusingly mounted out of the aforementioned directory yet there being a
>        `mingw64` directory that similarly contains `bin` `etc` `lib`
>        `libexec` `share` `ssl` that don't seem to get mounted and refers to
>        `C:\Users\MyUserName\` as the home dir.
>    - If I run `vim` it runs the `/usr/bin/vim` contained version that's build differently than the windows version, and opening `:e %MYVIMRC`
>        opens `~/.vim/vimrc`
>    - It maps `C:` to `/c/`
> 2. [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) which runs
>
>    - [mintty](http://mintty.github.io/) too, out of `C:\cygwin\` with `bin` `dev` `etc` `home` `lib` `sbin` `tmp` `usr` `var` in it where the home dir is within that
>        `home` instead of my windows homedir.
>    - If I run `vim` it hangs until I press control-c, which closes the window too.
>    - It maps `C:` to `/cygdrive/c/`
>    - It is noticeably slower, even at the prompt.
> 3. Github Desktop for Windows, which has an executable called `git shell` which can be configured to run `bash` and then runs a prompt
>      that is not mintty using
>
>    - [mingw64](http://mingw.org/) but out of somewhere like `C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_ahashofacommit\`
>    - It maps `C:` to `/c/`
>    - If I run `vim` it runs the windows installed version that read `:e $MYVIMRC` from `~/vimfiles/vimrc/`
> 4. [Gnu on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki), which gives some exe files in a `C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow\bin` these can run in any of the previous environments
>      and also the Windows cmd.exe prompt/shell.
>
>    - Fast, easy to install, but quite limited in adding anything onto them.
>    - Run with `cmd.exe` it maps `C:` to `C:`.
>    - Run with `cmd.exe` `vim` runs in the window with off colors and reads `:e $MYVIMRC` from `~/vimfiles/vimrc`.
> 5. [Vim for Windows](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc), which can run `gVim` right from the start menu, or `gvim`/`vim` from the command prompt.
>
>    - It reads `:e $MYVIMRC` from `~/vimfiles/vimrc/`
>    - gVim maps `C:` to `/`
>
> I won't get into the oddness around supposed cross-platform software
>   ranging from Eclipse, Visual Studio Code, to MySQL, and more niche
>   items like MIT-Scheme. I'll just say they're imperfect even if the
>   first two are nearly well polished.   The Java environment is
>   relatively interoperable, but retains a preference for a Unix style
>   that seems un-native.
>
> It gets even more confusing as one moves forward trying to install and
>   run something like [Apache Drill](http://drill.apache.org/) or another generally for unix
>   tool which has a Windows version. You can't run it in anything but the
>   cmd.exe prompt, but in that prompt it unhooks input accidentally
>   piping the input to the prompt. For example.
>
> So were is the unifying Unix toolset for windows? Is it still Cygwin,
>   if so, why is it so slow and painful and hard to add non-standard
>   packages to? Does everyone just run Linux/FreNetBSD/Minix in a virtual
>   machine or what's going on that this mess is the new normal? Microsoft
>   HAD Windows Services for Unix, but that was neither here nor there and
>   it's deprecated. Does Microsoft have no reason to try making an
>   official way to get, or build ported unix software in some light
>   semi-virtualized posix way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess a question along the lines of "How do I install Vim on Windows? What are the pros and cons of each way of installing?" would be on-topic, and not overly broad (see similar questions discussing the plugin managers and installing plugins).

It might get some downvotes, but I expect such a question to remain open.

Answer (score 5):

> some odd things aren't working (like tab completing help topics nor commands nor files) and running vim in the cmd.exe messes up the colors very much

It looks like you're having a few problems with Vim on Windows. I'm pretty sure the tab completion is just some setting; and running Vim from `cmd.exe` is a different question entirely. It's not immediately obvious to me what the pasted question is asking exactly, but I *think* you want to run Unix tools (`grep`, `sed`, etc.) from Vim on Windows? That doesn't directly relate to the first two questions either.

In other words, it looks like you can ask three questions: *"Tab completion doesn't work in Windows"*, *"Colours don't work when running Vim from cmd.exe"*, and *"How can I run Unix tools from Vim in Windows?"*

Putting them all in a *"I'm having a bunch of problems with Windows"*-question doesn't really work very well. Just ask three (or more) questions, one for each problem.